# I don't want the Facebook Like button to count my shares

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

Every time I share a page from my blog on Facebook, the Facebook Like button in the article is counting the Share as a Like. How can I make this stop?

Answer (score 1):

You need to just share it as a status update and not via the share buttons on your blog.

You can  filter out IP addresses for stat counters like google analytics but I don't know that it's a Facebook option at the moment.